# Template Linked List: No member available error

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, templates, linked-list

Please have a look at the following code

**LinkedList.h**

```
template <typename T>

class LinkedList
{
public:
    T *first;

    LinkedList()
    {
        first = 0;
    }
    ~LinkedList(){}


    T *Delete()
    {
    }

    T *Delete(const int key)
    {
    }

    void Display()
    {
    }

    T *Find(const int key)
    {
    }

    void Insert(T* newLink)
    {
        //newLink->next = first;
        //first = newLink;
    }

    bool IsEmpty()
    {
        return (first==0);
    }
};
```

**Weapon.h**

```
#pragma once
#include "GameObject.h"
#include "Stack.h"
#include "Round.h"

class Weapon :
    public GameObject
{
public:
    Weapon(int);
    ~Weapon(void);

    Stack <Round>   stack1;
    Weapon *next;

    void Display();
};
```

**Weapon.cpp**

```
#include "Weapon.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

Weapon::Weapon(int size) : stack1(size)
{

}


Weapon::~Weapon(void)
{
}
```

In here, Weapon represent links within a linked list. `Next` is a pointer to the next weapon in the list. But how can I access it? My attempt in `Insert()` method of the Linked List didn't work. I have commented them. Please help!

Comment: What do you mean by "didn't work" ?

Comment: @us2012: I can't point to the 'next'. No member available, intellisense says.

Answer (score 1):

```
    void Insert(T* newLink)
    {
        //newLink->next = first;
        //first = newLink;
    }
```

Will not "work" because `T` is a template type. It may or may  not contain "next" element. This is wrong way to use Templates.

`T` should be the type of data that is held by the `LinkedList`.. not the `LinkedList` itself.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class LinkedList 
{
  struct Node {
    T data;
    struct Node *next;
  };

  Node *head,*tail;

  void init(T& data)
  {
    if(head == NULL){
      head = new Node;
      head->data = data;
      head->next = NULL;
      tail = head;
    }
  }
public:
  LinkedList()
  {
    head = NULL;
    tail = NULL;
  }
  LinkedList(T& data)
  {
    head = NULL;
    tail = NULL;
    init(data);
  }

  ~LinkedList()
  {
    deleteLinkedList(head);
  }

  bool IsEmpty()
  {
    if(head == NULL) return true;
    return false;
  }

  void Display()
  {
    for(Node *h = head; h != NULL; h=h->next){
      cout << h->data;
    }
  }

  void Insert(T data)
  {
    if(this->IsEmpty()){
      init(data);
      return;
    }
    Node *n = new Node;
    n->data = data;
    n->next = NULL;
    tail->next = n;
    tail = n;
  }

  void deleteLinkedList(Node *hd)
  {
    if(hd->next == tail){
      delete tail;
      tail = hd;
      return;
    }
    deleteLinkedList(hd->next); 
  }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  LinkedList<int> list;
  list.Insert(10);
  list.Insert(20);
  list.Insert(30);
  list.Display();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: ohh man, I guess I am in a trouble! So how to solve it? Please help. New to C++!

Comment: You mean I need to cast the "T" inside LinkedList into "Weapon" ? The "T" inside insert() ?

Comment: ofcourse, @Yohan, you may need to do some operator overloading (`<<` with `ostream`)

Comment: that is upto you to define @yohan. i fixed the linkedlist only

Comment: OK, I think I am in a confusion. I thought the "Weapon" class is the "Node" here. It seems like not right? I can see you have replaced it with a struct. Please let me know :)